# ARM-V7-A ADD instruction combined with LSL

Tags: arm, armv7

```
add r1, r1, r0, lsl #3
```

I am not sure about the operation executed with this instruction.
Does it mean:

1. Add r0 and r1, take the result and execute a left shift of 3 bits, then save the result in r1
   or
2. Add r1 and (r0 left shifted of 3 bits) then save the result in r1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it means, shift value in `r0` by 3, after that add value in `r1` to `r0 << 3` and place it into `r1`. or `r1 = r1 + (r0 << 3)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the arithmetic and logical instructions in the Thumb and Thumb-2 instruction sets take three arguments.  The first is the *destination register*, the second is the *first operand* (also a register), and the third is the *flexible second operand*.  (If the destination register is omitted, the first operand is used as the destination.)

In almost all cases, the flexible second operand can be:

- A register
- A register with a shift or rotate applied, where the available shifts are

  - `ASR #n` (arithmetic shift right)
  - `LSL #n` (logical shift left)
  - `LSR #n` (logical shift right)
  - `ROR #n` (rotate right)
  - `RRX` (rotate right one bit through carry)
- A constant in the format `#constant`, where `#constant` can be:

  - Any constant that can be produced by shifting an 8-bit value left by any number of bits within a 32-bit word
  - Any constant of the form `0x00XY00XY`
  - Any constant of the form `0xXY00XY00`
  - Any constant of the form `0xXYXYXYXY`

So in your case, `r0, lsl #3` is the second operand to the `add` instruction, and so the shift is performed before the add.

For more information see the [ARM developer documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/general-data-processing-instructions/operand2-as-a-register-with-optional-shift).